# Help with SQL Server Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I need some assistance with a join I am trying to do in SQL Server to create a view with a breakdown of customers by state in my database.

**Table1:**

```
CustomerID, Gender, CustomerType
```

**Table2:**

```
CustomerID, State, City, Zipcode
```

I want a view at the end to have the following (example):

```
ID| State | Males | Females | PlatinumCustomer | GoldCustomer | SilverCustomer
1    FL      200     300           40                 200           260  
2    MO      200     400           40                 300           360
```

The values for my `Genders` are `M` and `F`, the values for my `CustomerTypes` are `P`, `G` and `S`.
Any help would be appreciated thank you!

Comment: Why are these in separate tables? Is this to allow multiple addresses or something?

Comment: Are the last 5 columns aggregates of some sort?  What does the ID represent in your desired results?

Comment: I don't see your table data, what data is resulting in this view ? Also how is the customer metal determined ?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a basic pivot table which should get you basically what you need.  You have an `ID` column in your example, which cannot be directly reproduced from your dataset. It would have to be calculated.

```
SELECT 
  State,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Gender = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Males,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Gender = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Females,
  SUM(CASE WHEN CustomerType = 'P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PlatinumCustomer,
  SUM(CASE WHEN CustomerType = 'G' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS GoldCustomer,
  SUM(CASE WHEN CustomerType = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SilverCustomer
FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON Table1.CustomerID = Table2.CustomerID
GROUP BY State
```

Comment: Missing the requested ID column, but otherwise tidy.  Not clear that it is anything more than a count of States.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
With Table1 AS
(
    Select 1 as CustomerId, 'M' Gender, 'Platinum' as CustomerType
    UNION SELECT 2, 'M', 'Platinum'
    UNION SELECT 3, 'F', 'Gold'
    UNION SELECT 4, 'M', 'Gold'
    UNION SELECT 5, 'F', 'Gold'
    UNION SELECT 6, 'M', 'Silver'
    UNION SELECT 7, 'F', 'Silver'
    UNION SELECT 8, 'M', 'Silver'
    UNION SELECT 9, 'F', 'Silver'
),
Table2 AS
(
    SELECT 1 as CustomerId, 'FL' State, NULL City, NULL ZipCode
    UNION SELECT 2, 'MO' State, NULL City, NULL ZipCode
    UNION SELECT 3, 'MO' State, NULL City, NULL ZipCode
    UNION SELECT 4, 'FL' State, NULL City, NULL ZipCode
    UNION SELECT 5, 'FL' State, NULL City, NULL ZipCode
    UNION SELECT 6, 'FL' State, NULL City, NULL ZipCode
    UNION SELECT 7, 'MO' State, NULL City, NULL ZipCode
    UNION SELECT 8, 'MO' State, NULL City, NULL ZipCode
    UNION SELECT 9, 'MO' State, NULL City, NULL ZipCode
)
Select 
    Row_Number() Over (Order By State) Id,
    State, 
    Sum (Case When Gender = 'm' then 1 else 0 end) as Males,
    Sum (Case When Gender = 'f' then 1 else 0 end) as Females,
    Sum (Case When CustomerType = 'Platinum' then 1 else 0 end) as PlatinumCustomer,
    Sum (Case When CustomerType = 'Gold' then 1 else 0 end) as GoldCustomer,
    Sum (Case When CustomerType = 'Silver' then 1 else 0 end) as SilverCustomer
From Table1 
    Inner Join Table2 
    on Table1.CustomerId = Table2.CustomerId
Group By State
```